# How to Add dependency between my gradle module and the "app" module with multiple flavors?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

Question: How can I configure Gradle to establish a dependency between my `testData` module and the `app` module with multiple flavors?

I'm currently working on a Gradle-based Android project, where I've created a module named `testData` that needs to depend on the `app` module. However, the `app` module has multiple flavors, and I'm unsure about the correct approach to set up this dependency, considering the different flavors.

I tried to use this approach, but it is not working:

```
implementation project(path: ':app', configuration: 'myFlavor')
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Project :testData declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to 
configuration 'myFlavor', which is not declared in the descriptor for project :app.
```

Any guidance or suggestions on achieving this configuration in Gradle would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Approach you mentioned does not work now with android. Android has its now own ART runtime and few different process than normal JVM build process.

Android developer docs do provide you something for your situation.

You have two options

- Either create same amount of build flavors for `testData` so that gradle can do the matching for you
- Use `matchingFallbacks` in your build.gradle script of `testData` and mention which variant of `app` module you want to use `testData`

Please refer this link for the usage: https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors